# Delete uploaded file from Heroku server

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've created a project that I can upload files, like Dropbox, deployed to Heroku and it works fine, but now I want to delete the file from Heroku server.

I delete the path from DB with the relation, but I tried lot of things to delete the file from the server but no success, last one via `fs.unlink()`, it seemed the best to be used:

```
//working example
const file = {url: 'https://mobox-app.herokuapp.com/files/dbd3917046ec3075f2a424e07c9a39aa-1*hoSDm9oecgsKShbAroI2XQ.jpeg'} 

async deleteFile(req, res){

        const file = await File.findById(req.body.fileId),
              fileId = req.body.fileId       

        await File.deleteOne( {_id: fileId}).then(

            fs.unlink(file.url, (err) => {

                if (err) {

                  console.error(err)

                  return

                }

            })

        )
}
```

This is what heroku logs give me:

```
2019-06-28T16:01:43.514606+00:00 app[web.1]: { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'https://mobox-app.herokuapp.com/files/dbd3917046ec3075f2a424e07c9a39aa-1*hoSDm9oecgsKShbAroI2XQ.jpeg']

2019-06-28T16:01:43.514645+00:00 app[web.1]:   errno: -2,

2019-06-28T16:01:43.514648+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'ENOENT',

2019-06-28T16:01:43.514650+00:00 app[web.1]:   syscall: 'unlink',

2019-06-28T16:01:43.514652+00:00 app[web.1]:   path:

2019-06-28T16:01:43.514654+00:00 app[web.1]:    'https://mobox-app.herokuapp.com/files/dbd3917046ec3075f2a424e07c9a39aa-1*hoSDm9oecgsKShbAroI2XQ.jpeg' }
```

It can't find the path, same if I put only `'/files/fileName.ext'` or only `'fileName.ext'` as the `file.url`. How can I delete these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've created a project that I can upload files, like Dropbox, deployed to Heroku and it works fine, but now I want to delete the file from Heroku server.

You might want to take a closer look and think about what "works fine" means.

Heroku's filesystem [is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem): any changes you make (like storing a file) will be lost the next time your dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day). Your uploads will be automatically removed, whether you like it or not.

Heroku [recommends](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) storing user uploads on a third-party service like Amazon S3. You'll have to migrate to something like that for the storage part to work properly, and when you want to delete a file you'll have to use whatever tools the service you've chosen provides.