# Deleting files periodically from Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I recently created a Flask Web app on Heroku where in I take some file from the user do some processing and return the processed file to the user. However I do not want to retain the files after processing for a very long time ( say I want to keep it just for 3 hours). What should I do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete uploaded file from Heroku server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810275/delete-uploaded-file-from-heroku-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku has a temporal file storage. Files are deleted periodically and thus temporary storage of files is bad. If you want to learn more, go here: [How to use heroku's ephemeral filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416738/how-to-use-herokus-ephemeral-filesystem)

The idea is every time a dyno is restarted, all temporary files are destroyed.

If you want to go around this, use `amazon s3`: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3